# window.open(blob, '_system') not working on facebook native browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is there a way that `window.open`  will work on facebook native browser?

I tried it on '*html2pdf*'  but it doesnt work. I tried it on just a normal url, but it just stays.

```
window.open(blob, '_system')
window.open(blob, '_blank')

window.open(url, '_system')
window.open(url, '_blank')
```